# Xcode 6, 4 inch treated and 3.5 inch display

Tags: ios, xcode6, screen-size

I am currently working on an `iOS` app and using new feature `Use Size Classes` in Xcode 6 with Swift language. Everything seems to work (elements are placed correctly for different screen sizes), but when I run my app on iPhone 5s(4 inch), the screen shown as 3.5 inch iPhone (The status bar would be placed where it would be on a 3.5 inch iPhone).

I have tried a lot to fix this by settings constraints even though it just keeps treating me the display as 3.5 inch display.

Extra info:
iPhone 5s device,
iOS 7,
Xcode 6 GM and
Single View application.
The issue happens even without making any changes to a fresh project.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You'll likely have a warning for your project telling you that you need to add (or have Xcode do it for you) a Default-568h@2x.png launch image to support retina devices. Just have Xcode add it for you and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, however, in the new xcode (xcode 6) launch images are no longer used, xcode now uses this .xib (storyboard) for the launch image. So you can no longer add a launch image just like that. The problem also happens already when i just make a new project and run it on iPhone 5s (iOS 7). No edits to the project.

Comment: An hour ago I had the same exactly problem, and was solved the way I mentioned it. I didn't want an xib for my launch image. I'm also using Xcode 6 GM

Comment: I also don't see a warning about it. Which xcode version are you using? (and which language)

Comment: Xcode 6 GM, Objective-C. I too created a branch new project and the same issue occurred. I don't think this is a code issue, I think it's a project issue.

Comment: Yea i think so too, maybe swift specific(the new launch image thing).

Comment: same issue, have you guys ever solved without dragging an image into it ? @user2078401

Comment: It turned out that mike was actually right. However, you first have to scroll down to launchimage in the main application view (where you would import frameworks and such) and click on import and select inages. It then creates a launchimage and then you just fill that one with your images.